# Using wildcards in "sources" for `rsync` command

Tags: command-line, backup, rsync, 21.10

I am trying to backup some files on another drive using `rsync`.

As a test case, I am trying the following command:

```
rsync -Rav --delete --stats /home/my_user/bin* "$dest"
```

This command will copy files and directories (with their contents) present in my `$HOME` directory and having names like  `~/bin`, `~/binb`, `~/bin1`, `~/bin2`, etc. to the destination.

However, when I delete any of the files or directories called `~/bin1` or `~/bin2` for example, these are not deleted in the destination too. The only thing that works is when there is a file in a directory say `~/bin2/file1` and this file is deleted, then this file is also deleted in the destination (but not in the case when the directory `~/bin2/` is removed altogether).

Obviously this problem is created by the shell expanding `/home/my_user/bin*` to all the file and directory names starting with `bin` in my `$HOME` directory at the time the `rsync` command is executed. So, I tried to quote the source like `"/home/my_user/bin*"`, but in this case I get the error:

```
rsync: [sender] link_stat "/home/my_user/bin*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

What options are needed, so, I can use wildcards for the source(s) and I will have the exact replica of the source file and directory structure, also in the destination?

Note: `rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31`

Comment: Did you try `--delete-after` instead of just `--delete`?

Comment: @ArturMeinild The end result does not change.

Comment: I guess you should use a different structure where you have everything in one parent only, `~/bin/1` `~/bin/2` ...

Comment: You need to consider pLumo's advice, unless you want to find a way to get the directory listing on the destination host to include as additional sources in your command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `--include` / `--exclude` like:

```
rsync -Rav --delete \
  --include="/home/my_user/bin*" \
  --exclude="/home/my_user/*" \
/home/my_user/ "$dest"
```

But I think it would be easier to have a different structure where you can sync only one parent directory.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, the `--include` option should be like this: `--include="/home/my_user/bin*"` (with no trailing slash).

Comment: ah yes, because you also want files starting with `bin`, fixed